# BitwiseXOR for Tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, xor, tensor

My project requests a new layer, which needs the new operator of Tensor to compute bitwiseXOR between input x and constant Key k.
E.g. x = 4 (bit form: 100), k = 7 (111), the bitwiseXOR(x, k) expects as 3 (011).

As far as I know, Tensor only has LogicXOR operator for bool type. Luckily, Tensorflow has the extended ability to have a new Op. However, I read the document in https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op, I can get the basic idea, but that is far from the implementation, maybe because of the lack of c++ knowledge. Any suggestions for implementation the new operator that will be helpful. Then I can use that new Op of Tensor to build the new layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your own C++ op, you can try with [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) which allows you to define a python function that operates on `numpy` arrays and is then used as a Tensorflow operation in the graph.

For your problem you can use [`numpy`'s bitwise_xor()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

t1 = tf.constant([2,4,6], dtype=tf.int64)
t2 = tf.constant([1,3,5], dtype=tf.int64)

t_xor = tf.py_func(np.bitwise_xor, [t1, t2], tf.int64, stateful=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  val = sess.run(t_xor)
  print(val)
```

which prints `[3,7,3]` as expected.

Please take care of the known limitations of this function (taken from the link above):

> **N.B.** The `tf.py_func()` operation has the following known limitations:
>
> - The body of the function (i.e. func) will not be serialized in a
>     `GraphDef`. Therefore, you should not use this function if you need to
>     serialize your model and restore it in a different environment.
> - The operation must run in the same address space as the Python program
>     that calls `tf.py_func()`. If you are using distributed TensorFlow, you
>     must run a tf.train.Server in the same process as the program that
>     calls `tf.py_func()` and you must pin the created operation to a device
>     in that server (e.g. using `with tf.device():`).